# Output format for command "size -A core-file-name"

Tags: linux

Running command:

```
size -A "core_file"
```

on a core dump (multithreaded program) shows multiple sections `loadNNN` with their sizes and addresses. Is there a way to use this information to find out which thread allocated one specific section, let's say `load101`? Appreciate your help!